# tika installation

Tags: solr, nutch, apache-tika

I integrated Tika with Solr following the instructions provided in [this link](http://www.abcseo.com/tech/search/integrating-solr-and-tika)

**Correct me if I am wrong**, it seems to me that it can index the document files(pdf,doc,audio) located on my own system (given the path of directory in which those files are stored), but cannot index those files, located on internet, when I crawl some sites using nutch.

Can I index the documents files(pdf,audio,doc,zip) located on the web using Tika?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two ways to index binary documents within Solr, both with Tika:

1. Using Tika on the client side to extract information from binary files and then manually indexing the extracted text within Solr
2. Using [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) through which you can upload the binary file to the Solr server so that Solr can do the work for you. This way tika is not required on the client side.

In both cases you need to have the binary documents on the client side. While crawling, nutch should be able to download binary files, use Tika to generate text content out of them and then index data in Solr as it'd normally do with text documents. Nutch already uses [Tika](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-766), I guess it's just a matter of configuring the type of documents you want to index changing the regex-urlfilter.txt nutch config file by removing from the following lines the file extensions that you want to index.

```
# skip some suffixes
-\.(swf|SWF|doc|DOC|mp3|MP3|WMV|wmv|txt|TXT|rtf|RTF|avi|AVI|m3u|M3U|flv|FLV|WAV|wav|mp4|MP4|avi|AVI|rss|RSS|xml|XML|pdf|PDF|js|JS|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|sit|eps|wmf|zip|ppt|mpg|xls|gz|rpm|tgz|mov|MOV|exe|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP)$
```

This way you would use the first option I mentioned. Then you need to enable the Tika plugin on nutch within your nutch-site.xml, have a look at [this discussion](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Using-Tika-to-crawl-doc-pdf-etc-tt603220.html#a603223) from the nutch mailing list.

This should theoretically work, let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I just customized the regex-urlfilter.txt by removing the lines you asked me to. Next I crawled a link having an image in it. Then, I send the crawled data over to solr. This is what I get.

Comment: <doc>
<float name="boost">1.0</float>
<str name="content"/>
<str name="digest">8189c36cedb58440686777e7d300c181</str>
<str name="id">http://lucene.apache.org/images/solr.png</str>
<str name="segment">20120801185310</str>
<date name="tstamp">2012-08-01T13:23:17.103Z</date>
<str name="url">http://lucene.apache.org/images/solr.png</str>
</doc>

Comment: But when I search the image through the solr front end,ie Ajax-Solr, it shows undefined . Is there any sort of mistake that i am committing ???

Comment: To make long story short, Ajax-Solr (through which I query solr) does not view any image.

Comment: Well, I don't think it could work with images, with binary documents I meant pdfs and so on. What do you expect to index out of your images? The problem you have is not on the Solr/nutch side, that part seems to work fine. By the way, do you know how StackOverflow works? I saw you haven't accepted nor upvoted any of the answers you previously got, you might want to do that and be thankful to people who helped you :)

Comment: I tried the same thing with pdf files. Crawled this http://www.imamu.edu.sa/DContent/IT_Topics/java/luceneinaction.pdf ....Got an xml output but no content. This is what I got.

Comment: <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
<float name="boost">1.0</float>
<str name="content"/>
<str name="digest">d8af41ad54c37623199c6f555e68c02c</str>
<str name="id">
http://www.imamu.edu.sa/DContent/IT_Topics/java/luceneinaction.pdf
</str>
<str name="segment">20120801194353</str>
<date name="tstamp">2012-08-01T14:14:00.095Z</date>
<str name="url">
http://www.imamu.edu.sa/DContent/IT_Topics/java/luceneinaction.pdf
</str>
</doc>
</result>

Comment: and I cannot vote up or vote down as I dont have much points/ratings to do so , else I would surely have. :-( Kindly forgive me for this.

Comment: Well, if you accept some of the answers you got you will get some points, then you hopefully can upvote too. That's how it works :)

Comment: ooopsss sorry...Didnt knew about this...I am new to SO. +1 to your answer. :-)

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you need to enable the Tika plugin on nutch within your nutch-site.xml, have a look at [this discussion][3] from the nutch mailing list.

Comment: I just added the property in nutch-site.xml. When I crawled using command line, it displays that "there are no URLS in the seed list". But there exist a url (http://www.imamu.edu.sa/DContent/IT_Topics/java/luceneinaction.pdf). It just not going well... please help me in rectifying the problem.